# Firewall blocking Android

Tags: c#, java, android, http, firewall

I wrote an application using a lightweight http server in c# called nancyfx. the problem is that i can call the framework from the browser(localhost and from LAN pc) but android (also LAN) gets blocked.

```
 String url = "http://192.168.178.35:8080/issue";
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

 HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
 HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
 HttpResponse res = client.execute(get, localContext);
```

It gets stuck in the execute method and looks like its waiting for a timeout. Then comes the http exception HttpHostConnectionException: connection refused.

If i turn off windows firewall it works. I also added a firewall rule for the program just in case.

Are there any special rules for Android devices?

Comment: You need to make a firewall rule on the windows server to allow inbound connections on port 8080. It has nothing to do with your android application.

Comment: You might also want to redict 8080 to your server ip in your router if you want to test it from outside your lan

Comment: It worked with the firewall rute for the port. By why not for the program? And then why did it work when i called it from another pc?

Comment: Verify that the android device on wi-fi is using the same lan as the pc. If the pc is using an ethernet cable, it may not be on same lan.

Comment: http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/